# Problems with two JInternalFrames sizes

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I have a `JDesktopPane` where I add and show a `JInternalFrame` called `ListarEmpleado.java`. From that `ListarEmpleado.java` I open another `JInternalFrame` called `InformacionEmpleado.java` doing click in a button. I have a equation to locate `InformacionEmpleado.java` in the middle of the `JDesktopPane` when it is opened.

This is the button event (I code in Netbeans):

```
private void masInformacionActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    InformacionEmpleado verDetalle = new InformacionEmpleado(this.cedulaSeleccionada);
    escritorio = getDesktopPane();
    escritorio.add(verDetalle);

    int width = verDetalle.getParent().getWidth();
    int width1 = verDetalle.getWidth();
    int height = verDetalle.getParent().getHeight();
    int height1 = verDetalle.getHeight();

    verDetalle.setLocation(width / 2 - width1 / 2, height / 2 -  height1/ 2 - 10);
    verDetalle.setVisible(true);
}
```

The problem is when the line `verDetalle.setVisible(true);` is executed, `InformacionEmpleado.java` is located in the middle perfectly and I don't have problems with it, but if I have `ListarEmpleado.java` maximized, it returns to its initial size (does not stay maximized). Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using the Windows Look and Feel?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: @MadProgrammer It depends of the OS, because I'm coding for Windows and Linux. But in the two operating systems that happens.

Comment: I know under windows, this seems to be the default behaviour, had the same issue, I think we switched to using `DefaultDesktopManager` instead